# Console Error: failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

When I try to print the current screenshot (for an iPad view) I get this weird error in console window:
`failed to find PDF header: %PDF not found`.

I wonder why this error is fired in console window ? why it's mentioning something related to `PDF` although I do not use any `PDF` related stuff in the whole project.

The code Im using to print the screenshot is :

```
  - (IBAction)print:(id)sender {

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
     else
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

     [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

     UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    //saving the file to documents directory

     NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Screenshot.png"];
     [imageData writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:YES];

     NSString *myFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Screenshot.png"];
    UIImage *screenShot = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot)];

     self.pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
      if (self.pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:myData] ) {

         self.pic.delegate = self;

        //filling up print info
         UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
         printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
         printInfo.jobName = [myFilePath lastPathComponent];
         printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
         self.pic.printInfo = printInfo;

         self.pic.showsPageRange = YES;
         self.pic.printingItem = myData;

        void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
         ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {

             if (!completed && error)
                 NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u",
                                      error.domain, error.code);
             };

        [self.pic presentFromRect:self.printButton.frame inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler: completionHandler];    // iPad


        }

    }
```

The file path (Screenshot.png) is correct, and it is correctly saved to documents directory.

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know which line, exactly, causes that console output. You could step through it in the debugger to find out.

My guess is that it's the call to `-[UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:]`. If you read [the documentation for that method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIPrintInteractionController/canPrintData%3a), you'll see that it has to check if that data contains PDF. It looks like it tries and fails, printing a message along the way.

Since generally no end users watch the iOS console, this is not a very important bug, apparently not important enough for Apple to fix.

Comment: this is the line that fires that error: [self.pic presentFromRect:self.printButton.frame inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler: completionHandler];

Comment: Guess I guessed wrong! But the OS X and iOS printing systems are generally based on PDF. Perhaps something else in the printing pipeline is doing a similar sort of check.

Comment: so, would that error cause problems in printing process ? I cannot test the printing process,'coz I do not have an AirPlay supported printer.

Comment: It's impossible to determine from just that console message. I would never ship printing code that I hadn't seen work on at least one real printer!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. I checked through every line and I found out that this is because you are printing data. And if you directly print image this weird warning will disappear. Because from Apple's file of the UIPrintInteractionController framework:

```
@NSCopying public var printingItem: AnyObject? // single NSData, NSURL, UIImage, ALAsset
```

The printingItem can be any one of the above four types. My guess is Apple takes data as PDF data by default, and apparently, this is no header data in the data you generated from UIImage.